# Using multiple databases for different endpoints

Tags: php, database, .htaccess, api, laravel

I have API written in lumen(laravel). I am using Eloquent for my models.
What I need to do is to use different databases based on url (endpoint). 
For example I have `http://apiprovider.com/api/v1/` as base API url and it connects to the `api_v1` database, but I need to use another database if v2 is used `http://apiprovider.com/api/v2` for instance `api_v2` database.
All classes and laravel application should be the same, only different database according to version.

Database settings is stored in `.env` file.

Please suggest the right way to implement this ? Or at least possible ways.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an idea, i haven't tried it but a simple way would be switching between the two databases from a middleware.

For example you could define the two connections available in `database.php` :

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql1' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'mysql2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST_2', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
```

Then create a middleware and switch the DB in the handle method

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check the request URL and decide what DB to use

    //set the DB for this request
    Config::set('database.default', $dbname );
}
```

I think that `Config::set('database.default', $dbname);` will work only for the current request, but it would do what you need